# Unable to toggle drop down value based on other column

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid

I need to make dropdown value in Ag-Grid dynamically changed based on value/condition of another column.

Already tried to toggle it with a function, extend it with Vue framework to make it reactive, and also with `gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs` but still no luck. (value changed on console but not rendered).

here's a snippet and screenshot.

```
colDef = [
      {'headerName': 'Steps',
        cellEditor: 'select',
        cellEditorParams: {
          values: store.globalData.stepsValues } // global var, change works on console
      }]
```

[image]

`Steps` column dropdown values here needs to dynamically changed based on a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made them reactive by injecting `colDef` parameter to Vue component, so it's now a reactive data.